# Jquery form element access

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to jquery and trying to do the following:

I have a form:

```
<form method="POST" class="add-product" >
...
<label name="message"></label>
...
</form>
```

And script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".add-product").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/product/add/",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $(form.elements["message"]).html(data.message);
        }
    });
});
```

});

I'm trying to update label with message, but it doesn't work. Seems that I have some mistake in syntax:

```
$(form.elements["message"]).html(data.message);
```

Comment: try `$(form).find('label[name="message"]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `label` does not appear in the `form.elements` collection. Instead you need to select it directly:

```js
$(".add-product").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = this;

  // inside the AJAX callback...
  var data = {
    message: 'Foo bar'
  }
  $(form).find('label[name="message"]').html(data.message);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" class="add-product">
  <label name="message"></label>

  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this will have adverse effect. There can be more than one `label` with name `message`. Also this same approach has been covered in other answer

Comment: Well yes, anything's possible, but the OP hasn't stated that. All we can go on is the information they have provided in the question. This answer also explains the issue and offers a working example.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, but another problem is that I have multiple forms and should change label only for form that was submitted

Comment: @AnishBalay this code does that - it uses the `form` reference to find the `label` within it

Comment: @Rajesh he states that there's multiple `label` within the *page* not the same *form*. The above code is fine for that situation.

Comment: Right - so what's the issue? That's the requirement the OP has outlined.

Comment: @AnishBalay no problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Try using the selector:

`$("form.add-product label[name='message']").html(data.message)`

You can read more about jQuery Attribute selector's here. https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

If you have more than one label on the page with the attribute `name='message'` then the above won't work.

Comment: OK but not in the use case the OP has given @Rajesh

Comment: Yes but if thats the case, even `$('label').html()` would do. Its our responsibility to have insight and answer that would cover a bit more cases that shown

Comment: Then you'd be writing answer's to cover an infinite number of use cases. The answer given is the right answer to the OP's question.

Comment: I'm sorry if I offended you in any manner. You can read comments under Rory's answer. OP have multiple forms with multiple labels. So this would not solve.

Comment: It's not a case of being offended @Rajesh. You're down voting a perfectly acceptable answer to the problem. My answer is the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: No. Rory is searching within the `form` and you are searching in entire DOM. As OP has stated that he has multiple forms, your code will change a lot more than it should. Also I downvoted as I suspected the impact it can have, but due to missing information, i revoked my vote. Now its clear so I request you to make necessary modifications

Answer (score 0):

You used wrong jquery selector, try it:

```
$('label[name="message"]').html(data.message);
```

hope this help;

Comment: Please see other answers. This has been covered.

Comment: I typed and answer late 3 min. sorry!